# customise window scrollbar using vanilla JS for browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

so far the only way i've been able to change the window scrollbar is by using CSS but it doesn't change the border radius on Firefox just the colour. Does anyone have a workaround using vanilla JS so scrollbar can be changed fully in all browsers?

The CSS i've used so is from W3Schools

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow, please read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: show the code you have used